# URL Rewriting in htaccess for single page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

my website link : https://example.com/about.php

Need to change link : https://example.com/about

Tried below code:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^about/?$ about.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But not working...
Any one please help, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is working on my end.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

and make sure you have enabled rewrite_module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```